# Proving Big theta for polynomials using quantificational definition

Tags: big-o, polynomial-math

How can I prove Big Theta using quantificational definition? I know that u have to find 2 constants such that c1*g(n)<= f(n)<= c2*g(n)- but how do you find these constants?

Could anyone help me prove the following to show an example 5x3 − 7x2 + 5x + 1 = Θ(x3)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume `x > 0`, which is usually what we have.

```
5x^3 − 7x^2 + 5x + 1 <= 5x^3 + 5x + 1
                     <= 5x^3 + 5x^3 + x^3          ; x >= 1
                      = 11x^3
```

On the other hand

```
5x^3 − 7x^2 + 5x + 1 >= 5x^3 - 7x^2
                     >= 5x^3 - 4x^3                ; if 7x^2 <= 4x3, i.e. x >= 7/4
                      = x^3
```

In conclusion, for `x >= 7/4` we have:

```
x^3 <= (5x^3 − 7x^2 + 5x + 1) <= 11x^3
```

and we are done.